# Unable to locate package pnp4nagios

Tags: apt, bash, software-installation

I'm having problems trying to find the pnp4nagios package. I don't know what to do.

```
apt-get install pnp4nagios -y
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Have you enabled the `universe` repository in your software sources?

Comment: What is the error message? This operation is normally accomplished using 'sudo' btw....

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, Yes, I have enabled the universe repository. I'm logged in as sudo. I don't know what to do haha.